# How to calculate $\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)} dt$?

Tags: integration

How to calculate  $\int_0^\pi \sqrt{1+\cos^2(t)} dt$ ? Seemly, this is not a elementary integrals ?

Comment: Your effort? {}

Comment: Looks like a complete elliptic integral.

Comment: Sometimes you can compute definite integrals of functions with no elementary integral

Answer (score 4):

This is
$$2\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{2-\sin^2t}\,dt=2\sqrt2 E(1/\sqrt2)$$
where
$$E(k)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2t}\,dt$$
is a [complete elliptic interval of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Complete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind).

In their book *Pi and the AGM*, Borwein and Borwein give the
formula
$$E(1/\sqrt2)=\frac{4\Gamma(3/4)^2+\Gamma(1/4)^2}{8\sqrt\pi}.$$